# np.random.randint: what does "byteorder must be native" mean?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

In the documentation of np.random.randint, it is given that:

```
Byteorder must be native
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, all built-in data type objects have a byteorder

```
‘=’ native 
‘<’ little-endian 
‘>’ big-endian 
‘|’ not applicable
```

Now what you will have to use depends on your computer's CPU, it's just a way how computer stores things e.g where the most significant bit will be?
So, by Byteorder must be native it means that you will use the byteorder that your system uses. You can check it by this code

```
sys.byteorder
```